# for loop result is printed twice

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

note: the letters are there twice so when shifting a letter at the end of the alphabet i dont get a out of range error

so currently im working on a caesers cypher where you write a word and shift those letters by a certain amount of times

```
input = abc 
output = bcd
```

my issue is when the code runs it prints the output letters twice

```
input = abc
output = bbccdd
```

heres my code

```
alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

direction = input("Type 'encode' to encrypt, type 'decode' to decrypt:\n")
text = input("Type your message:\n").lower()
shift = int(input("Type the shift number:\n"))


def encrypt(text, shift):
    cipher_text = ""
    for i in text:
       for letter in alphabet:
           if i == letter:
               index = alphabet.index(letter)
               shifted_index = index + shift
               shifted_letter = alphabet[shifted_index]
               cipher_text += shifted_letter
    print(f"The encoded word is {cipher_text}")
encrypt(text, shift)
```

another example

```
input = zulu
expected output = avmv
code output = aavvmmvv
```

Comment: i have the letters twice because when shifting a letter towards the end of the alphabet

Comment: to only need the alphabet once use: `shifted_letter = alphabet[(index + shift) % len(alphabet)]`

Answer (score 2):

Lots of work for what is essentially a one-liner:

```
import string
alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase   # use the predefined string of lower case letters from the string module
index = {ch: i for i, ch in enumerate(alphabet)}   # pre-calculate the index of each character once.


def encrypt(txt, n):
    return ''.join(alphabet[(index[c] + n) % len(alphabet)] for c in txt)


print(encrypt('spin', 5))
```

prints

```
xuns
```

the modulo operation (ie. `... % len(alphabet)`) makes sure the index is within bounds of the alphabet after adding the shift - no matter how big the shift is.

Answer (score 1):

leave it at "for i in text" their is no need for "for letter in alphabet" that is why it is looping through. If that doesnt work take out the duplicates in your alphabet. I didnt notice that on first glance.

Comment: okay but how do i get it to check if the word letter is equal to the alphabet

Comment: make a different function called check that you run first that makes sure that the input is only alphabetical.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, you have the same alphabet twice. So, you need to exit the inner for loop once you have shifted. So, add a `break` after `cipher_text += shifted_letter`, that will exit the inner for loop.

**Updated Code**

```
alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

direction = input("Type 'encode' to encrypt, type 'decode' to decrypt:\n")
text = input("Type your message:\n").lower()
#shift = int(input("Type the shift number:\n"))


def encrypt(text, shift):
    cipher_text = ""
    for i in text:
       for letter in alphabet:
           if i == letter:
               index = alphabet.index(letter)
               shifted_index = index + shift
               shifted_letter = alphabet[shifted_index]
               cipher_text += shifted_letter
               break # NEW LINE
    print(f"The encoded word is {cipher_text}")

shift = int(input("Type the shift number:\n"))
if shift > 26:
    print("Shift should be max 26, exiting...")
else:
    encrypt(text, shift)
```

**Output**

```
Type 'encode' to encrypt, type 'decode' to decrypt:
encode
Type your message:
spin
Type the shift number:
5
The encoded word is xuns
```

**Updated based on feedback**

```
import string

direction = input("Type 'encode' to encrypt, type 'decode' to decrypt:\n")
text = input("Type your message:\n").lower()
shift = int(input("Type the shift number:\n"))

alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase   # use the predefined string of lower case letters from the string module
index = {ch: i for i, ch in enumerate(alphabet)}   # pre-calculate the index of each character once.

def encrypt(txt, n):
    return ''.join(alphabet[(index[c] + n) % len(alphabet)] for c in txt)

encrypt(text, shift)
```

**Output**

```
Type 'encode' to encrypt, type 'decode' to decrypt:
encode
Type your message:
xylophone
Type the shift number:
100
'tuhkldkja'
```

Comment: Now try to shift "xylophone" 10 letters...

Comment: answer is rsfijbihy

Comment: `hivyzryxo` - Did I miss something? He has a-z twice. But, yes, if the shift is > 26 and you enter z, that will crash :-). Updated code to msg if > 26 and exit.

Comment: why not just use a modulo on the length of the alphabet (and alphabet could be a string instead of a list - much faster to type if you're not going to use `string.ascii_lowercase`)

Comment: There's really no need for the inner `for` loop and if you drop that you don't need the `break`. If you can fix a wrong code by removing parts that's better than doing the fix by adding extra parts to an already overengineered solution.

Comment: Thanks @thbjorn and Mathias. My idea was to make minimal changes to the code to get the problem resolved, as I don't know if there are other reasons user has the code the way he/she has. I have added the response with the shorter version as well (borrowed fully from above response) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the inner `for` loop and the `if` and then find the first index of the current character in the alphabet.

```
def encrypt(text, shift):
    cipher_text = ""
    for i in text:
        index = alphabet.index(i)
        shifted_index = index + shift
        shifted_letter = alphabet[shifted_index]
        cipher_text += shifted_letter
    print(f"The encoded word is {cipher_text}")
```

This code sticks closely to your approach. There are better solutions, like the one from @thebjorn.